# Page is not loaded when using SI4T TBB

Tags: search, si4t, dynamic-publishing

We are using SI4t for elastic search in pour project. We have created a module under deployer extension to push the data into the Elastic Search.

1. TBB is working fine
2. indexed search data generating properly
3. Push data into the Elastic Search is also working fine.

But the page is published along with the indexed search data in to the database. As a result we are unable to get the content of the page.

### Update

Here are the sample of page.html after publishing the page using that TBB

```
<!-- <INDEXED DATA> { Search  data } </INDEXED DATA> --> { DD4T json data of the Page }
```

Comment: Here are the sample of page.html after publishing the page using that TBB -

<!-- <INDEXED DATA> { Search  data } </INDEXED DATA> --> { DD4T json data of the Page }

Comment: Hi - which jar file are you using - did you download the latest version? Would it be possible to post an entire transaction as DEBUG log? And did you make any customizations for Elastic Search ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am checking the latest version now. I will let you know If I face any issue later.

Answer (score 2):

If the SI4T storage extension is working correctly then the index data would be removed from the content stored in the broker database. The fact that this index data is still in there indicates a problem with the storage extension. Perhaps your Elastic Search indexer implementation is causing an exception which does not prevent indexing, but stops the index data being stripped out. If this is the case then there is probably something in the logs to indicate a problem - can you post/link to a full debug log when publishing a single page?

Note that there is an [open issue](https://github.com/SI4T/SI4T/issues/4) to support adding index data in JSON format, to prevent this from being a blocking issue in implementations that publish content/data in JSON format, however the fact remains that something is going wrong in the deployer if this index data remains in the content stored in the broker DB.

Comment: Hi Will I am checking with the new version of jar file. I will let you know if I faced any issue after that.

Answer (score 1):

Will in this case we are using the old version of SI4T. I have now deployed the new jar and tested it again. Everything is working now. Thanks for the help.